# KrakenD - prevent changing response

Tags: exception, configuration, krakend

I'm newbie with KrakenD. I tried configure this API Gateway to not modify my response from backend. Here is excerpt from ma configuration:

```
"endpoint": "/mycompany/someservice/{id}",
         "output_encoding": "no-op",
         "backend": [{
                 "url_pattern": "/someservice/{id}",
                 "host": [
                     "http://host-in-our-company:8080"
                 ],
                 "encoding": "no-op"
             }
         ]
     }
```

In this GET request we ask about some entity. When entity does not exist our Spring application the throws the and exception and status 404 is returned. The original response without KrakenD looks like this:

```
    "timestamp": "2021-10-04T14:47:58.918+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/mycompany/someservice/115_EXIST"
}
```

But when I use KrakenD the response is as follows:

```
{
    "cause": "Entity with id 115 cannot be found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
}
```

This correspond to the exception which is thrown when entity cannot be found:

```
ERROR com.my.company.exception.GlobalRestExceptionHandler - Error caught: Entity with id 115 cannot be found.
```

How can I configure KrakenD to achive this behaviour? Or maybe I should change in some way implementation in our backend?

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 1):

The `no-op` encoding does not perform any modification to the backend response. The response you are seeing is the actual response from the backend without any intervention from KrakenD.

Be aware that consuming content through KrakenD is not the same as directly consuming the backend, as KrakenD won't pass any headers, query parameters or cookies to the backend until you say so. For instance, your backend might expect an `Accept` header that the client is sending, but unless you forward it in the configuration it won't reach the backend (see `headers_to_pass` in the documentation). This is an example of common problems that make backends respond differently. See in your backend code when this error message is triggered, and also try to consume the backend directly using a  `curl`